# Remove a sequence of timestamps, where a certain condition is True

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lubridate

**Background:**

I have a dataset, df, and would like to record the 'Connect' datetime and remove an Action where:

IF the ‘Connect’ action is immediately followed by an action, where the next action from it, is repeating, or <= to 60 seconds, keep iterating until you reach an ‘Ended” value (that does not show this conditional behavior) and record this time.

The output pattern should always follow a 'Connect' and 'Ended'

```
We start with:

Connect            4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM

Then look to the next line:

Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM

Now look to the line that follows:

Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM


These two timestamps are less than or equal to 60 seconds, so we keep going    
until we come across an Ended value where these conditions do not apply. 
So the Ended value of 

Ended              4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM    gets recorded.




Action             Time

Connect            4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM
Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM
Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM
Connect            4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM
Ended              4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM
Connect            3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM
Ended              3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM
Ended              3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM
```

Essentially, I would like to remove this part of the dataset:

```
Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM
Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM
Connect            4/6/2020 1:15:21 PM
Ended              3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Action              Time

Connect             4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM        
Ended               4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM
Connect             3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM
Ended               3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM
```

The output pattern should always follow a 'Connect' and 'Ended'

**Dput:**

```
structure(list(Action = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("Attempt", "Connect", "Ended"), class =     "factor"), 
 Time = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label =      c("3/31/2020 11:00:08 AM", 
 "3/31/2020 11:14:54 AM", "3/31/2020 4:17:43 PM", "4/6/2020      1:11:41 PM", 
  "4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM", "4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM", "4/6/2020  1:15:21   PM", 
 "4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM"), class = "factor")), class =     "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

**This is what I have tried:**

I am thinking that I should use a loop, but not exactly sure on how to construct this. Any help is appreciated.

```
  library(lubridate)
  if (value <= 60) {
   print("") 
   } else {
   Expr2
   }
```

Comment: When you come across the first value that is associated with the 'Connect' string, (Connect            4/6/2020 1:11:41 PM) look to the value that follows this, (Ended              4/6/2020 1:14:20 PM) and if the value that follows (Attempt            4/6/2020 1:15:20 PM) is less than or equal to 60 seconds, remove and keep iterating until you come to the next 'Ended' string value ( 4/6/2020 2:05:18 PM). Pattern should always be 'Connect' and an 'Ended'

Comment: why not just index `Attempt` and drop it `df[-Attempt_idx, ]`, what is the significance of <60 sec?

Comment: So I’m comparing data to a known dataset. The known dataset shows me that the ‘true’ activity is a connect at 1:11:41AM and an end at 2:05:18 PM. If I just remove the ‘attempt’, that would give me an End at 1:14:20, which  is not correct (as it will not match my source which shows an end of 2:05:18 PM. I was looking for the pattern of how the second source generates the end times. It appears that the data in between is ignored IF, (conditions above in first part of the post)

Comment: And how did you form your timestamps, what class is it over and above factor? Is there any other identifying info as it seems these must be Connect A 1:11:41AM End B 1:14:20 & etc.

Comment: These time stamps weren’t formed by me, it is being generated by an outside source. I am trying to mimic its pattern. It appears to ‘skip’ any timestamps that follow this pattern: after the connect time stamp is established, we have an action, followed by another action that is <= to 60sec appears to ‘skip’ . The end time should be 2:05:18 (so we must ignore the time stamps that are in between 1:11:41 and 2:05:18